# Source in Moreh Nevuchim which speaks of the reason why the Torah mentions the genealogy of the nations and why they were dispersed

Tags: sources-mekorot, tanach, rambam, parashat-noach

Can anyone find me the exact wording of the Rambam in his Sefer Moreh Nevuchim, where he states that...

> a fundamental principle of the תורה is that the universe was created ex nihilo, and  אדם was the forerunner of the human race since the human race was later dispersed over all the earth, and divided into different families speaking very dissimilar languages, people might come to doubt that they could all have originated from one person. Therefore the Torah records the genealogy of the nations, why they were dispersed, and the cause of the formation of their different languages.

(Quoted in the interlinear artscroll chumash [parashas noach 11:1-9])

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is in [Moreh Nevukhim (3:50)](https://www.sefaria.org/Guide_for_the_Perplexed%2C_Part_3.50.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en):

> 

והם אלו הספורים אשר ספר בתורה, אשר יחשבו רבים שאין תועלת בזכרם, בספרו **הסתעף המשפחות מן נח ושמותם ומקומותם**, וכן בני שעיר החורי **וספר המלכים אשר מלכו בארץ אדום וכיוצא בהם**, וכבר ידעת אמרם שמנשה הרשע לא היה מרבה מושבותיו הפחותים רק בדקדוקי אלו המקומות, אמרו היה יושב ודורש בהגדות של דופי, **היה אומר לא היה לו למשה לכתוב אלא ואחות לוטן תמנע**, ואני אודיעך כלל אחד, ואשוב אחר כן אל הפרטים כאשר עשיתי בטעמי המצות. **דע כי כל ספור שתמצאהו כתוב בתורה הוא לתועלת הכרחית בתורה**, אם לאמת דעת שהוא פנה מפנות התורה, או לתקון מעשה מן המעשים, עד שלא יהיה בין בני אדם עול וחמס. ואני אסיר לך הספק, **כאשר היתה פנת התורה שהעולם מחודש ואשר נברא תחלה היה איש אחד ממין האדם והוא אדם הראשון**, ולא היה באורך הזמן אשר מאדם עד משה רבינו רק אלפים וחמש מאות שנה בקרוב, **ואילו בא להם זה הספור לבד היה האדם מסופק בדבר, כי נמצאו אז בני האדם מפוזרים בקצוות הארץ כלה ומשפחות חלוקות ולשונות חלוקים רחוקים מאד, והוסר הספק הזה ביחסם כלם וזכרון הסתעפם**, וזכר שמות המפורסמים מהם פלוני בן פלוני ושנותיהם, ולהגיד מקום שכנם, והטעם המביא להתפזרם בקצות הארץ, והטעם המביא להחלק לשונותם, ושמתחלה היו במקום אחד ושפה אחת לכולם, כי כן ראוי להיותם בני איש אחד.

> THERE are in the Law portions which include deep wisdom, but have been
> misunderstood by many persons.; they require, therefore, an
> explanation. I mean the narratives contained in the Law which many
> consider as being of no use whatever; e.g., the list of the various
> families descended from Noah, with their names and their territories
> (Gen. x.); the sons of Seir the Horite (ibid. xxxvi. 20-30); the kings
> that reigned in Edom (ibid. 31, seq.); and the like. There is a saying
> of our Sages (B Ṭ. Sanh. 99b) that the wicked king Manasse frequently
> held disgraceful meetings for the sole purpose of criticising such
> passages of the Law. "He held meetings and made blasphemous
> observations on Scripture, saying, Had Moses nothing else to write
> than, And the sister of Lotan was Timna" (Gen. xxxvi. 22)? With
> reference to such passages, I will first give a general principle, and
> then discuss them seriatim, as I have done in the exposition of the
> reasons of the precepts.
>
> Every narrative in the Law serves a certain purpose in connexion with
> religious teaching. It either helps to establish a principle of faith,
> or to regulate our actions, and to prevent wrong and injustice among
> men; and I will show this in each case.
>
> It is one of the fundamental principles of the Law that the Universe
> has been created ex nihilo, and that of the human race, one individual
> being, Adam, was created. As the time which elapsed from Adam to Moses
> was not more than about two thousand five hundred years, people would
> have doubted the truth of that statement if no other information had
> been added, seeing that the human race was spread over all parts of
> the earth in different families and with different languages, very
> unlike the one to the other. In order to remove this doubt the Law
> gives the genealogy of the nations (Gen. v. and x.), and the manner
> how they branched off from a common root. It names those of them who
> were well known, and tells who their fathers were, how long and where
> they lived. It describes also the cause that led to the dispersion of
> men over all parts of the earth, and to the formation of their
> different languages, after they had lived for a long time in one
> place, and spoken one language (ibid. xi.), as would be natural for
> descendants of one person. (Friedlander Translation)