# Sefer for significance of names in Torah

Tags: jewish-books, names

I am looking for a sefer which delineates the significance and meaning of many names in Torah, but more specifically the lists of names, found in Noach, Vayeira, Chayei Sarah, Vayishlach, Vayigash, etc.

For example, the Torah tells us the names of Yishmael's twelve sons. What is the significance of the Torah telling us his sons? Why bother?

Another example: the Torah tells us the names of Yokshan's and Midian's sons. What is the significance and why bother?

etc.

Comment: "significance" as in their identities?

Comment: @Oliver That and also why the Torah needs to tell us them. There are many names that the Torah does not bother to tell is because they are not significant enough.

Comment: @JoshuaPearl Like? The only possible example I can think of is the genealogy mentioned in Bamidbar and Pinchas - but those names are mentioned not for themselves, but their progeny (i.e. which family they are from).

Comment: Please edit clarifications into the post. Such as what you mean by significance.

Comment: Since each one could be a different explanation, this question is too broad to answer.

Comment: General answer to much of these: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/78666/8775.

Comment: Since there is no reason to assume that one source will discus all of these, you can improve your likelihood of getting a satisfactory answer by editing the question to ask for a source that discusses them in general, or some or all of them.

Comment: @sabbahillel Of course it isnt. It is looking for one book. Nothing broad about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the [אוצר אישי התנ"ך](https://www.hamadaf-y.co.il/%D7%97%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%AA/%D7%AA%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94-%D7%A0%D7%91%D7%99%D7%90%D7%99%D7%9D-%D7%9B%D7%AA%D7%95%D7%91%D7%99%D7%9D/%D7%A2%D7%95%D7%93-%D7%91%D7%AA%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94-%D7%A0%D7%91%D7%99%D7%90%D7%99%D7%9D-%D7%9B%D7%AA%D7%95%D7%91%D7%99%D7%9D/%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A6%D7%A8-%D7%90%D7%99%D7%A9%D7%99-%D7%94%D7%AA%D7%A0%D7%9A/), also [available in English](http://www.artscroll.com/Products/ISHL.html). It lists every person in Tanach, and what is known about them, gathered from "the seven seas of sefarim" (Talmud, Midrash, etc.).

Comment: Although I love that seffer, I think you will not find any entries for the personalities the OP is looking for. That seffer has sources from chazzal about 'famous' people in Tanach. The OP seems to be looking for 'all the other guys'.